# Bind a collection of a model to only a part of another collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the requirement to select/map only a few of datasources for each of my applications, by first selecting the application on the left then the mapped/selected (few) datasources on the right (see screenshot).

I often have such a scenario as a business requirement, however I wasn't able to come up with a good solution to model this using WPF bindings.

Given the following code:

**The models:**

```
class DataSource
{
    public DataSource(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

class SoftwareSolution
{
    public SoftwareSolution(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.DataSources = new ObservableCollection<DataSource>();
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DataSource> DataSources { get; private set; }
}

class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.SoftwareSolutions = new ObservableCollection<SoftwareSolution>();
        this.SoftwareSolutions.Add(new SoftwareSolution("Software 1"));
        this.SoftwareSolutions.Add(new SoftwareSolution("Software 2"));
        this.SoftwareSolutions.Add(new SoftwareSolution("Software 3"));

        this.AllAvailableDatasources = new ObservableCollection<DataSource>();
        this.AllAvailableDatasources.Add(new DataSource("SQL Server"));
        this.AllAvailableDatasources.Add(new DataSource("Oracle"));
        this.AllAvailableDatasources.Add(new DataSource("DB2"));
        this.AllAvailableDatasources.Add(new DataSource("MySQL"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataSource> AllAvailableDatasources { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SoftwareSolution> SoftwareSolutions { get; private set; } 
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Application" />
    <ListBox Margin="0,25,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding SoftwareSolutions}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="DataSources" />
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding AllAvailableDatasources}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <!-- how should I bind this checkbox? -->
                    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**The GUI:**

[image: example gui]

**What pattern can I use to "bind" the checkboxes on the right to the selection on  the right?**

Comment: What I did was to create a custom control containing properties like `ItemsSource`, `SelectedItems` and `ItemTemplate` which wraps items in a view-model with `IsSelected` property and updates the `SelectedItems` collection accordingly. Then, using templates, you can present the items in any way you want (as `ListBox`, `ComboBox` etc.). It was a bit of a fuss but since my project uses this control 50+ times it was so worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `DataSourceVM` which has a `DataSource` and an `IsSelected` property. Each `SoftwareSolution` has its own collection of `DataSourceVMs`, and the checkboxes are bound to `IsSelected`.

```
public SoftwareSolution(string name, IEnumerable<DataSource> dataSources)
{
    Name = name;
    this.DataSources = new ObservableCollection<DataSourceVM>(dataSource.Select(x => new DataSourceVM(x));
}
```

Comment: That solution would solve the `IsSelected` binding problem, however now I have to manually sync all the own collection of the `DataSourceVMs` with the `AllAvailableDatasources`, right?

Comment: Correct, but you should populate AllAvailableDatasources first, then just pass it into the constructor of each SoftwareSolution. It's then trivial to create the DataSourceVMs using Linq as shown above.

Comment: I'll go with that solution knowing it has issues when `AllAvailableDatasources` can also be dynamically changed.

Comment: You can always subscribe to the CollectionChanged event in such circumstances. It's slightly more complicated but I do similar all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your `ObservableCollection` using an `ICollectionView`, which is the standard approach in these kind of scenarios.

In particular you'll have an event wired on the left which will change the `ICollectionView` and that will be bound on the column on the right.

More infos about the `ICollectionView` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Using `ICollectionView` with a filter would result in Oracle and MySQL not beeing listed at all since they would not be part of the view the listbox is bound to. Am I missing anything?